# How can I get clickable HTML internal (anchor) links in Android AlertDialog?

Tags: android, html

Is it possible to have a clickable **internal** link (anchor link) within the AlertDialog? This link should not call an external web page it should only jump to an achor link.
I tried it with href="#jumptarget" and `<a name="jumptarget">` . But I got an error.

My HTML Code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <body>
  <h1><a name="jumpstart" href="#jumptarget">Jump</a></h1> 
  <p>Some Text... </p>
  <h1><a name="jumptarget">Jump Target</a></h1>
  </body>
  </html>
```

My Java code:

```
    int listId = R.raw.instructions;
    String instructions = "";
    instructions = loadTextRessource(listId);
    TextView msg = new TextView(this);
    msg.setText(Html.fromHtml(instructions));
    msg.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    msg.setClickable(true);
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDlg.setTitle("Instructions" );
    alertDlg.setView(msg);
    alertDlg.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
    alertDlg.show();
```

The showed result is clickable but I get an ActivityNotFoundException exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution: Use WebView instead of TextView